# Route to internal network via PC through VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

I have a Windows PC at work which has access to internal network.
When I connect to network of the company via VPN I have access to my PC, but not to the internal network.
Is it possible to organize route to the intrenal network from my home PC through my PC at work? Probably with some additional tools?
Actually I just want to login on some servers in the internal network through ssh without using rdp on my work PC.

Comment: You need to ask your IT department about this. If your VPN connection isn't already providing the access you want they've probably configured it that way intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only access your pc through VPN from home, this is a restriction implemented by your Company in order to prevent exactly what you want to do. Having your home network's traffic routed into your Company's network is very dangerous and generally a bad idea. Very few are the chances that your home is protected as or better than your Company's and that's why this restriction is in place. If you have admin access to your work PC you will be able to turn it into a router using the builtin Internet sharing in Windows or by bridging the connections, and if linux you may enable ip forwarding and set it up as a router.
I won't explain how to do this in depth as i discourage such a practice and i am on the side of who in your Company decided to put such a restriction in place. Even, please note that the methods i have suggested may not work depending on how restrictions are implemented on this VPN, which VPN it is, your home's network topology, your company's network topology, etc. You did provided very few details in order to receive help better than this.